# How can I clear tables with ManyToOne relationship using TypeORM

Tags: node.js, jestjs, typeorm

I have two Entities with ManytoOne relationship between them:

Entities:

- PersonalProfile
- Language

Their relation is defined as:

```
import BaseModel from "@models/BaseModel";
import { Entity, ManyToOne } from "typeorm";
import Language from "@models/Language";

@Entity()
export default class ProfessionalProfile extends BaseModel {
  @ManyToOne(() => Language, { nullable: false })
  language: Language;
}
```

So, in my test setup, I'm creating some instances in the beforeEach and I'm trying cleanup the database in the afterEach. That's my afterEach code:

```
import PersonalProfileRepository from "@repositories/PrefessionalProfileRepository";
import AppTestsDataSource from "@tests/config/database/data-sources";
import Language from "@models/Language";

const { manager: entityManager } = AppTestsDataSource;

afterEach(async () => {
  await PersonalProfileRepository.clear();
  await entityManager.clear(Language);
});
```

Since I'm first removing all PersonalProfile instances, I was supposing that I would be able to clear the Language table as well. But I'm getting this error:

```
QueryFailedError: Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`hey_freela_test`.`professional_profile`, CONSTRAINT `FK_b785f751abc8ecd343bbae0f324`)

      at Query.onResult (src/driver/mysql/MysqlQueryRunner.ts:222:33)
      at Query.execute (node_modules/mysql2/lib/commands/command.js:36:14)
      at PoolConnection.handlePacket (node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:456:32)
      at PacketParser.onPacket (node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:85:12)
      at PacketParser.executeStart (node_modules/mysql2/lib/packet_parser.js:75:16)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:92:25)
```

What I'm doing wrong here? What's the correct way to clean up my database in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In ManyToOne relation, add onDelete: 'CASCADE'